# mongoose or mongo node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I am working on MERN Stack project right now and Got confuse to whether use mongo driver which was made for node.js or to use mongoose framework.

I cannot get the basic details , usage , and architecture of both of the framework. Please help me to find out which one to use ..